# Normalizing constant for beta distribution with discrete prior : R code query

Tags: r, bayesian

I am currently going through **Bayesian Thinking with R** by Jim Albert. I have a query about his code for his example with a beta likelihood and discrete prior. His code for calculating the posterior is:

```
pdisc <- function (p, prior, data) 
    s = data[1] # successes
    f = data[2] # failures

    #############
    p1 = p + 0.5 * (p == 0) - 0.5 * (p == 1)
    like = s * log(p1) + f * log(1 - p1)
    like = like * (p > 0) * (p < 1) - 999 * ((p == 0) * (s > 
        0) + (p == 1) * (f > 0))
    like = exp(like - max(like))
    #############

    product = like * prior
    post = product/sum(product)
    return(post)
}
```

My query is about the highlighted bit of code for calculating the likelihood and what the logic behind it is (not explained in the book). I'm aware of the pdf for the beta distribution, and that the log likelihood will be proportional to `s * log(p1) + f * log(1 - p1)` but it is not clear what the following 2 lines are doing - I imagine it's something to do with the normalizing constant, but again there isn't an explanation for this in the book.

Comment: The second line starting with `like=` is just a way to set to zero (actually to `exp(-999)`) the likelihood when `p` is either 0 or 1. In the following line he is multiplying the likelihood by a factor of `exp(-max(like))` maybe to avoid loss of precision due to having too close to zero numbers.

Comment: However, I don't get why he is not using `dbeta`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
like = like * (p > 0) * (p < 1) - 999 * ((p == 0) * (s > 
    0) + (p == 1) * (f > 0))
```

takes care of the edge cases when you have prior probability at 0 or 1. Basically, if p=0 and any successes are observed then like=-999 and if p=1 and any failures are observed then like=-999. I would have preferred to use -Inf rather than -999 as that is what the log likelihood is in those cases.

The second line

```
like = exp(like - max(like))
```

is a numerically stable way to exponentiate when only the relative differences in the logged values are important. If like were really small, e.g. you had lots of successes and failures, then it is possible that exp(like) would be represented as a 0 vector in a computer. Only the relative differences are important here because you renormalize the product to sum to 1 when constructing the posterior probabilities.